# Remove UIToolBar Buttons not working

Tags: xcode4.1

I'm trying to hide toolbar buttons. First In my viewDidLoad I hide some of them and that works perfectly. I do not want to hide btnCreateReport Yet. I just use:

```
NSMutableArray     *items = [[myToolBar.items mutableCopy] autorelease];
[items removeObject: btnEmailReport];
[items removeObject: btnSaveToIpad];
[items removeObject: btnPrintReport];
[items removeObject: btnNewInspection];
myToolBar.items = items;
```

Later when I try to Hide 2 of them using:

```
NSMutableArray     *items = [[myToolBar.items mutableCopy] autorelease];
[items addObject: btnEmailReport];
[items removeObject: btnSaveToIpad];
[items addObject: btnPrintReport];
[items addObject: btnNewInspection];
[items removeObject:btnCreateReport];
myToolBar.items = items;
```

the btnCreateReport does not go away.  What can cause something like that?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It's Fixed.  Turns out The code works perfectly. Just a newbie mistake. I was using it in the wrong ibAction.